# Multiple casting

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to get my head around this line of code, which I came across today:

```
(int[])((int[])((Object[])((Object[])this.mapping.get(index)))[0])
```

where `mapping` is a Vector.

It seems to have redundant casting and unecessary casting from Object[] to int[] when one could simply have done (int[])this.mapping.get(index) assuming the entry is of type int[]. Could anyone explain to me why the above expression would be needed? Thanks

Comment: Proper typing and using generics would avoid that hell, but you've provided why too less context to tell more. For example is it really just `Vector` or does it have a generic type? What does it contain?

Comment: its just a vector as far as I can tell:    private Vector mapping = new Vector(); It contains an int[]

Comment: Then read this: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Comment: It's ugly, but I guess it's a good example of why you should not use raw types. Also, sure looks like it contains an `int[][]`.

Comment: :-O Forget compiling, this code shouldn't _exist_.

Comment: @Pshemo, it does compile. I picked it up from a relatively complex class where the author of the code is trying to store mappings between columns. I myself dont have the full context and I am trying to understand the code and I found this particular snippet quite intriguing, hence the question

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tom, it was helpful

Answer (score 3):

Since all those parenthesis are difficult to read, here is a match-up:

```
(int[])((int[])((Object[])((Object[])this.mapping.get(index)))[0])
│     │││     │││        │││        │                │     │││   │
└─────┘│└─────┘│└────────┘│└────────┘                └─────┘││   │
       │       │          └─────────────────────────────────┘│   │
       │       └─────────────────────────────────────────────┘   │
       └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Exploded, to show the order of evaluation:

```
                                     this
                                         .mapping
                                                      index
                                                 .get(     )
                          ((Object[])                       )
               ((Object[])                                   )
                                                              [0]
       ((int[])                                                  )
(int[])
```

As you can see, both the second `Object[]` cast and the second `int[]` cast are redundant.

The code could be simplified to:

```
(int[]) ((Object[]) this.mapping.get(index))[0]
```

Or even simpler:

```
((int[][]) this.mapping.get(index))[0]
```

Even better, if `mapping` was declared as `Vector<int[][]>`, the code would simply be:

```
this.mapping.get(index)[0]
```

Comment: Maybe add a link to the raw types and stress out that this kind of code merits prison time? Perfect answer though!

Comment: @JanezKuhar We don't know that OP is using a *raw* type. It could be an `Vector<Object>` or `Vector<?>`.

Comment: Well, we do, he wrote that in a comment ;P.

Answer (score 1):

Lets replace for a second `this.mapping.get(index)` with `obj`. Also lets add some leveling for better visualization of what is happening here. So instead of

```
(int[])((int[])((Object[])((Object[])this.mapping.get(index)))[0])
```

we can write it as

```
(int[])(
    (int[])(
        (Object[])(
            (Object[])obj
        )
    )[0]
);
```

Part

```
        (Object[])(
            (Object[])obj
        )
```

is just double casting to same type, so we can skip one `(Object[])` which gives us

```
(int[])(
    (int[])(
        (Object[])obj
    )[0]
);
```

Next part

```
    (int[])(
        (Object[])obj
    )[0]
```

is more confusing. [Precedence order table](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) shows that `[]` has higher precedence than `(type)` casting so `(type)element[index]` is same as `(type)(element[index])` which means we are actually casting first element (`Object` at index 0) to `int[]`.

Lastly we are casting `int[]` again to `int[]` which is redundant.

So your expression can be reduced to `(int[])((Object[])this.mapping.get(index))[0]` or `(int[])(((Object[])this.mapping.get(index))[0])` which may be *little* less confusing.

---

To make it work `this.mapping.get(index)` should return `Object[]` array (or its subtype like 2D array `int[][]`), which should hold as first element `int[]`.

So it can be

```
new int[][]{{1,2},{3,4}};
```

but also something like

```
new Object[]{new int[]{1,2}, "foo"};
```

Comment: You are casting first element (at index 0) from `Object` to `int[]`, not `Object[]` to `int[]`. After the index lookup, the type is `Object`, not `Object[]`.